# How to get values in CDATA in XML file with PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I have a puzzling situation with a CDATA string from XML I am accessing.

I am access an XML API and collecting the CDATA string in PowerShell. It returns like this:

```
aggressorAllianceID: 99006227
aggressorCorpID: 244898283
aggressorID: 1283793762
armorValue: 1.0
hullValue: 1.0
moonID: 40043321
shieldValue: 0.5166110755741394
solarSystemID: 30000686
typeID: 20060
```

As you can see there are multiple lines. I want to collect this to variables so for example `$aggressorAllianceID = 99006227`.

The full XML is here:

```xml
<eveapi version="2">
<currentTime>2017-07-19 09:08:18</currentTime>
<result>
<rowset name="notifications" key="notificationID" columns="notificationID">
<row notificationID="644139237">
<![CDATA[
aggressorAllianceID: 99006227 aggressorCorpID: 244898283 aggressorID: 1283793762 armorValue: 1.0 hullValue: 1.0 moonID: 40043321 shieldValue: 0.5166110755741394 solarSystemID: 30000686 typeID: 20060
]]>
</row>
</rowset>
</result>
<cachedUntil>2027-07-17 09:08:18</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

I have tryed to parse the CDATA string with the split command but I'm not really getting awhere?

Can anyone provide me an example of how they would access and variable this CDATA information?

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way of storing data like that is a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx). Use the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet for transforming a list of key=value pairs in a string to a hashtable data structure. Since your data has colons instead of `=` you need to replace them first.

```
$cdata = @'
aggressorAllianceID: 99006227
aggressorCorpID: 244898283
aggressorID: 1283793762
armorValue: 1.0
hullValue: 1.0
moonID: 40043321
shieldValue: 0.5166110755741394
solarSystemID: 30000686
typeID: 20060
'@

$ht = $cdata -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Then you can access the individual values like this:

```
$ht['aggressorID']
$ht['hullValue']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**<sub>Undeleted due to Tomalak's helpful comments - please read before considering `New-Variable`</sub>**

[Ansgar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186388/5039142) is a better way to store this data and deal with this programmatically. To answer your literal question of how to get, for example `$aggressorAllianceID = 99006227`, you can use [New-Variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable)

*input.txt*

```
aggressorAllianceID: 99006227
aggressorCorpID: 244898283
aggressorID: 1283793762
armorValue: 1.0
hullValue: 1.0
moonID: 40043321
shieldValue: 0.5166110755741394
solarSystemID: 30000686
typeID: 20060
```

---

```
$myReturnedValues = Get-content .\input.txt
foreach($line in $myReturnedValues){
    New-Variable -Name ($line.Split(": "))[0] -Value ($line.Split(": "))[2]
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea *at all* to let a program create variables with arbitrary, non-predictable names. The hashtable approach is the way to go.

Comment: @Tomalak In my code I use `New-Variable` combined with `Get-Variable` to store and retrieve predictable data based on unique IDs. Fully admit data-storage is a weak area of mine, and will try to use Ansgar's approach when refactoring in future. Is this approach with regard to OP's data so bad that it's likely to cause harm/lead to further issues?

Comment: Well, any self-modifying code (and code that creates variables in the same scope it runs in is just that) is open for attack (SQL injection or cross-site scripting are the most prominent examples) or random breakage at run-time because it's easily possible that an existing variable is overridden. This will lead to unexpected program behavior. Keep your program logic clean and prevent injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the explanation.